# Getting error: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

when I'm trying to get responce.

Json response I am getting is below:

```
[  
   {  
      "site":"bash.im",
      "name":"bash",
      "desc":"Цитатник Рунета",
      "link":"/url.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbash.im%2Fquote%2F445088",
      "elementPureHtml":"Text"
   },
   {  
      "site":"bash.im",
      "name":"bash",
      "desc":"Цитатник Рунета",
      "link":"/url.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbash.im%2Fquote%2F445087",
      "elementPureHtml":"Text"
   },
   {  
      "site":"bash.im",
      "name":"bash",
      "desc":"Цитатник Рунета",
      "link":"/url.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbash.im%2Fquote%2F445086",
      "elementPureHtml":"Text"
   }
]
```

My model class:

```
public class PostModel {

@SerializedName("site")
@Expose
private String site;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("desc")
@Expose
private String desc;
@SerializedName("link")
@Expose
private String link;
@SerializedName("elementPureHtml")
@Expose
private String elementPureHtml;

public String getSite() {
    return site;
}

public void setSite(String site) {
    this.site = site;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public String getElementPureHtml() {
    return elementPureHtml;
}

public void setElementPureHtml(String elementPureHtml) {
    this.elementPureHtml = elementPureHtml;
}

}
```

Connecting class:

```
    public class App extends Application {

    private static UmoriliApi umoriliApi;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www.umori.li/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        umoriliApi = retrofit.create(UmoriliApi.class);
    }

    public static UmoriliApi getApi() {
        return umoriliApi;
    }
}
```

And MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<PostModel> posts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        posts = new ArrayList<>();

        App.getApi().getData("bash", 50).enqueue(new Callback<List<PostModel>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<PostModel>> call, Response<List<PostModel>> response) {
                posts.addAll(response.body());
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<PostModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Will appreciate any help or tips.

Comment: there is an error in response that's why gson is not able to convert response to model class.

Comment: i think the error is in the web service response you can test the request on the browser to make sure it is matching your model

Comment: @Badr, I made my model according to json responce using jsonschema2pojo.org service

Comment: @Jaydeep Patel, could you please prompt, where exactly an error?

Comment: check webservice in post man . there might be problem of params or response.

Comment: @Jaydeep Patel, I have already use HttpLoggingInterceptor to check, and that's allright: D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://www.umori.li/api/get?name=bash&num=50 (85ms)

Comment: you are right, but response is not come which we wanted. it is some thing like this: http://dpaste.com/00YDWVX

Comment: @Jaydeep Patel,I'm a little bit confused) So, what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix this?

Comment: check api/web service or parameters, your android code is working fine,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit2:Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 268 path $\[0\].images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226370/retrofit2expected-begin-array-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-268-path-0-ima)

Comment: @Jaydeep Patel, thank you, but unfortunately still I haven't found any solution

Answer (score 7):

try to clean builder build->clean project it worked